# Mountable engine routing error in Rails 4 after upgrade from Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm having some trouble with some **mountable** engines within our Rails 4.2.4 app. We recently (I know, it's sad how late we are to the game) upgrade from Rails 3.2.23. Our engine routes worked fine in Rails 3.2.23, but when I try to visit the routes now (using [Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) or cURL), I get a RoutingError, no route matches. However, when I look at the output of `rake routes` or `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` the route does in fact exist with the right verb and everything.

Things I looked into:

- The route isn't overwritten by something else down the file, because we have everything wrapped in subdomain constraints.
- I've recreated the mountable engine, using the latest version of Rails and compared differences.

Also, I'm using the [versionist](https://github.com/bploetz/versionist) gem. I don't know if that's what's causing it or not, but it seems relevant.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'api', path: 'engines/api'
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
constraints subdomain: /^api/, format: :json do
  mount Api::Engine, at: "/"
end
```

**engines/api/lib/api/engine.rb**

```
module Api
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Api

    config.generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :rabl
      g.test_framework  :rspec, view_specs: false
    end
  end
end
```

**engines/api/config/routes.rb**

```
Api::Engine.routes.draw do
  api_version(:module => "V1", :parameter => { :name => "version", :value => "1" }) do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

**Sample cURL request**

```
curl -X "GET" "http://api.myapp.dev:3000/users/new?api_key=foobar&version=1" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

**log/development.log**

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/new"):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  rollbar (2.3.0) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  request_store (1.2.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
  passenger (5.0.20) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:94:in `process_request'
  passenger (5.0.20) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:151:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (5.0.20) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:112:in `main_loop'
  passenger (5.0.20) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  passenger (5.0.20) src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:112:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Comment: can you paste in the curl command you use

Comment: @Phil I added a sample cURL request for you

Comment: in your development.log, do you see anywhere in the request where it tries and fails to access the a database record, or does it just fail outright at the routing stage? I've seem things appear as RoutingError when a 404 is raised in a validation for example. Maybe you could provide a snippet of the rake routes that shows this request pattern?

Comment: The failure is definitely just a RoutingError, it never actually touches code within my project (as you can see by the development.log snippet above). I also updated the routes and cURL request.

Comment: definitely would be good to see a snippet of the rake routes output. Just a silly thought. Have you tried a post or put/patch request? Also have you tried a GET with something like http://api.myapp.dev:3000/users.json (I see your constraint is for JSON requests and your curl is passing those headers, but just wondered just in case something has changed in the middleware it could be tricked...)

Comment: Yes, I have tried other requests. This snippet that I've given is a great representation of what's going on. There isn't any route in the engine that's working, regardless of the HTTP verb being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out the answer, it was an ever so subtle change in the syntax accepted in constraints. I ended up removing the format constraint above the `mount` call and moved that into the engine routes. The code now looks like this:

**config/routes.rb**

```
mount Api::Engine, at: '/', constraints: { subdomain: /^api/ }
```

**engines/api/config/routes.rb**

```
Api::Engine.routes.draw do
  api_version(module: "V1", parameter: { name: "version", value: "1" }) do
    constraints format: :json do # Added the format constraint here.
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps someone as it took me a while to nail down the problem.